# Volume of cubes thrown in a container

Tags: volume, randomness, solid-mechanics

I am trying to calculate how many lego bricks I can fit in containers of a given sizes.

Basic 1x1 lego brick is **8 x 8 x 9.4 mm** so it has a volume of ~600 mm²

[image]

Then we have a container of size **192 x 148 x 63 mm**

[image]

The question is **how much of these bricks can I fit into this container**, given they are not arranged optimally, but rather just thrown in there randomly.

[image]

My idea is to just remove 20% for the space between the bricks.

$$ \frac{volume\ of\ container}{volume\ of\ brick}\ - 20\% $$

Comment: an upper bound can be obtained by considering the optimal arrangement, and a lower bound by taking them to be spheres with diameter equal to the diagonal of the cube.

Comment: You could fill a small reference cube to calibrate your 20% estimate.
Or a simulation could be written for calibration purposes.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform:  I have my doubts that assuming spheres would give a lower bound.  Maybe it would almost always be true in practice, but I can imagine a situation where pieces could end up forming an arch shape with a large void underneath.  Were you speaking in general terms, or do you know of a reference proving that assuming spheres gives a lower bound?

Comment: You might also consider asking this question at [math.SE] instead (please don't crosspost!), given that things like "circle packing" are traditionally considered more geometry than physics problems.

Comment: @James I'm not sure what the odds of something like that are; but they seem unreasonably low.  Also, for a little perspective on how much low the bound will be with spheres; the diagonal is 14.7 mm, meaning the radius is 7.35 and the volume of each sphere is 1663 mm^3, over twice the volume of the rectangle.  Factor in that rectangles can be packed to fully fill up the space while spheres can't; and it seems like a very conservative lower bound.

Comment: @JMac:  You might be right.  However, you say that rectangles "can" be packed to fully fill up the space, but the OP already said that is not what he's doing.  Therefore, I don't think that point is justification for your lower bound being conservative.

Comment: No, but it is the upper bound.  I was trying to point out just how big the difference between low and high estimates are.  Mostly I was trying to say that not only do the spheres take up 2.75x the volume per sphere, but they also have a much lower packing factor (since the rectangles pack perfectly).  That means the sphere assumption gives a lower bound for volume filled as less than a third of the volume of the prism.  I'd say that accounts for even your worse case of arches developing and such.